# Можно ли сделать так что бы Console.ReadKey не останавливал цикл?(не ожидал нажатия клавиши)

Tags: c#

Мне нужно что бы персонаж двигался по координатам сам, а я нажимая стрелочки определял его направление, пока только смог сделать движение по нажатию(нажал-двинул).
Как считывать клавишу только когда ее жмут а не ожидать в каждой итерации цикла?
Либо просто узнать что была нажата клавиша и если была нажата нужная клавиша, изменить направление.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialisationCharacters();
        char[,] map;
        map = MapData("maps//map1.txt");
        map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
        DrawMap(map);
        while (true) {
            Move(map);
        DrawMap(map);
            if (hero.points == 253)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("GOOOD JOB! YOU ARE WINNER!!!");
    }

    static public void Move(char[,] map)
    {

        ConsoleKey s = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
        if (s == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            if(map[hero.y, hero.x-1] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y, hero.x-1] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y,hero.x]=' ';
                hero.x = hero.x - 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }

        }
        else if (s == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y, hero.x + 1] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y, hero.x + 1] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.x = hero.x + 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
        else if(s == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y - 1, hero.x] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y - 1, hero.x] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.y = hero.y - 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
        else if (s == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y + 1, hero.x] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y + 1, hero.x] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.y = hero.y + 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Я кнш не эксперт, но по-моему стоит смотреть в сторону событий...

Comment: @JohnnyRage Спасибо, за направление

Comment: Можно из другого потока делать `Cosole.ReadKey()`, и, да, как-то бросать информацию из дочернего потока в главный.

Comment: Используйте `Console.KeyAvailable` для проверки, есть ли нажатая клавиша.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо @Alexander Petrov, использовал `Console.KeyAvailable` для проверки нажата ли кнопка.

Создал переменную `key` для клавиши, записываю какая именно клавиша была нажата в `tmpKey` и сверяю нужная ли это кнопка, если да записываю в переменную `key` и цикл работает с ней.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InitialisationCharacters();
        key = ConsoleKey.LeftArrow;
        char[,] map;
        map = MapData("maps//map1.txt");
        map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
        DrawMap(map);
        ConsoleKey tmpKey = ConsoleKey.Enter;
        while (true) {
            Thread.Sleep(170);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                tmpKey = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            }
            if(tmpKey == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow || tmpKey == ConsoleKey.RightArrow || tmpKey == ConsoleKey.UpArrow || tmpKey == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
            {
                key = tmpKey;
            }
            Move(map,key);
            DrawMap(map);
            if (hero.points == 253)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("GOOOD JOB! YOU ARE WINNER!!!");
    }

    static public void Move(char[,] map, ConsoleKey key)
    {
        if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        {
            if(map[hero.y, hero.x-1] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y, hero.x-1] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y,hero.x]=' ';
                hero.x = hero.x - 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }

        }
        else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y, hero.x + 1] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y, hero.x + 1] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.x = hero.x + 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
        else if(key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y - 1, hero.x] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y - 1, hero.x] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.y = hero.y - 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
        else if (key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow)
        {
            if (map[hero.y + 1, hero.x] != '*')
            {
                if (map[hero.y + 1, hero.x] == '-')
                    hero.points += 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = ' ';
                hero.y = hero.y + 1;
                map[hero.y, hero.x] = hero.name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`ConsoleKey s` нужно сделать статическим полем. После этого, где-то в `Main` сделать вот такую фигню:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        s = Console.ReadKey().Key;
    }
});
```

А из `Move` убрать `ConsoleKey s = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;`.

Можно сделать аналог на событиях или каким-нибудь другим из множества способов организации конкурентного ввода-вывода.

На всякий случай, поясняю:

1. Цикл обработки перемещения больше не ждёт ввод, а смотрит значение переменной.
2. Значение переменной меняется из другого потока.
3. Другой поток большую часть своего времени стоит в ожидании ввода (по этому рекомендую ещё `async` сюда добавить)
4. Другой поток меняет значение переменной когда происходит ввод.

Таким образом персонаж будет продолжать двигаться после единовременного нажатия клавиши.

Comment: Когда задачу можно полноценно решить без параллельного или асинхронного программирования, лучше это делать так. Особенно начинающему разработчику. Прикрутить `async` можно легко и к ответу автора, но зачем? Итого, ваш совет вредный, потому что потенциально рождает больше проблем, чем решает. Я рекомендую удалить этот ответ.